# Best WYSIWYG editor for mailing (or best way to use.. for mailing)

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, mailing-list

for one of my customers I've been developing a mailsystem for his clients. His clients have been collecting e-mailaddresses in their stores and want to start using these for mailings once in a while.

I'm aware of all possible things that can go wrong, but as far as I can see we've got it pretty much covered the best way we can. We're using SMTP (Authenticated) to send the e-mails to the customers, e-mails are signed serverside, we're splitting up the mails with a max of 25 per 5 minutes, sending headers to optout location, etc. I can imaging this is just the tip of the iceberg concerning all things I have to take care off.. but I warned my customer that he might be better of using an existing app like MailChimp but he insisted on doing it ourselfs.

After the development of our beta version was done, we've ran some tests and all things went pretty well in fact. Haven't had any spamfolder problems, all mails are good to read in the different clients, and so on.

However, one thing is being a little hard right now.. the editor! We're creating templates for our clients (1 template, 6 styles). Our clients can load these into their editor and edit the text inside. As far as we (and the client) can see, everything goes pretty good, however - the editor does not create e-mail friendly HTML code (I should have known...)

I've searched the net for some articles/how-to's but there's really less to find about this.

Currently we're using `CKEditor` (Editor) and `KCFinder` (Image Plugin). As far as I know, CKEditor is the best free WYSIWYG available... but is it any good for e-mail editing?

I noticed some companies use a custom editor (MailChimp) others used TinyMCE (Enormail.eu).

Anyone has a good recommendation? Or is CKeditor the best option, but do I need to modify some of the settings to get the best possible html code for mailings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "e-mail friendly HTML code"?

Comment: well, I'm not 100% sure myself. I get the templates delivered "sliced for e-mail". Basically, as far as I know e-mail templates are build up using tables and inline CSS attributes. Also; not all CSS will work in e-mail clients. If I could I would tell you all the differences, but e-mailmarketing isn't my business either unfortunately. I'm trying to gather as much knowledge as possible at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done a little research about it, because I'm interested in using CKEditor for E-Mail-based editing too.

Generally, CKEditor is the best WYSIWYG web editor, but you have to use some techniques that are not used usually in HTML pages.

Since your'e using templates (I guess CKEdtior's `config.templates`) most of your optimization will be in your templates, and not no configuration of CKEditor.

**These are the main goals:**

- Don't use the `<style>` tag - instead, use inline styles (the `style` attribute). Some webmail readers does not read this tag.
- **Do not** use `config.fullPage = true;` since some readers does not read the `<body>` tag.
- Instead of using `<body>`, `<div>`, and other tags used for layout, use tables. Yes, this technique is old, but by doing this you can make sure that (almost) all readers will render the page correctly. Instead of applying styles to the `<body>` tag, use these style to the main `<table>` tag.
- Don't use absolute positioning. Tables can also take part in the solution.
- For all images - Insert the `alt` attribute, **and** for all width and height optimizations, don't use CSS-based width and height. I mean - Instead of `<img style="width: 100px;" />` use `<img width="100px" />`.

**In addition**, one of the important things, is to customize and optimize [output formatting](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting). I personally change at least `breakAfterOpen : true` inside `writer.setRules('p')`.

**CKEditor** is the most popular WYSIWYG web-based HTML editor, and I guess there is no other web-based editor for Email.

**One more thing that I can think of**, is that after your client is finished writing his message, there will be an option for him to preview the message in some popular mail clients. There are many Email testing and preview tools out there, but unfortunately I didn't find anything free.

I really hope that it helped someone!

Comment: The templates are delivered including a html <head/> and <body/> tag. Also I added `fullPage=true` since CKEditor was removing the <head/> tags while editing. The delivered templates have a little CSS in the <head/> tags, such as: body/link color.

As far as I know, I must try to use as basic code as possible (using old inline style tags such as the <img width="100"> tag). So apart from your recommedation to NOT use fullpage, everything is covered already.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not using config.templates. The templates are e-mail ready HTML files. Which are loaded as content into the textarea when the page loads (simply by using file_get_contents() or a similar function in PHP).

Comment: I doubt that fullPage=true is bad, since - for example - CampaignMonitor is using templates WITH head/body tags. Disabling this would remove parts of the css and headerinformation of the mailing.

Comment: @PENDO , the `<head>` tag is redundant, because all readers just don't see it. All readers, or at least webmail, Have to handle all your message, inside their own page - so unless they are using `<iframe>`, the <head> tag just doesn't work, and the <body> MAY not work in some readers. instead of <body>, use a table, and all styles applied to the body, should be applied to the table. And just a question - why are you not using the built-in templates service? I hope you know that you can customize the templates. `fullPage` is bad only because <head> and <body> are bad too.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the built-in template service. I'm gonna take a look into this as soon as possible. The client prefers system extensions before bugtesting and perfecting the core of the system (*sigh*.. customers..)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked for three years on a webmail. I could try [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) or [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/). None provides a perfect solution. You still encounter problems and you should always add functionalities. Some are too heavy, too slow, lack of features.

The one I found most effective is that of Gmail, but unfortunately, the code is not available.

The best solution is to create **your WYSIWYG** an even currently.

**UPDATE**

Try [Squire](http://neilj.github.io/Squire/) made by FastMail.